# Which of these codes will run faster

Tags: c++, optimization

I have recently begun to think about optimisation, now I know there are many books and articles but I have a particular scenario i'm interested in.

A.

```
for (i = 0; i < limit + 5; i++)
  cout << test;
```

B.

```
limit2 = limit +5;
for (i = 0; i < limit2; i++)
  cout << test;
```

What I want to know is would the second piece of code run faster because it only has to do the mathematical calculation once or is the calculation stored for the lifetime of the loop.

Comment: Both has same complexity to run.

Comment: Both will fail to compile :-)

Comment: @Tadeusz: OP corrected the code, but I LOLd ;)

Comment: The capital F I accept but it would have worked fine with the curly braces, Is there a reason beyond personal coding style you removed them.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're focusing on an optimization that almost certainly doesn't matter, regardless of how it gets compiled. Focus on picking the right algorithms and design for the rest of your code. Profile to find out what's slow and optimize the areas that take the most time. Typically 10% of the code takes 90% of the time. You're currently thinking about a very small part of the 90% of the code that takes far less than 10% of the time in just about every possible scenario beyond having an empty loop block.

Comment: I was really just wondering if coding style had a noticeable impact on speed.

Comment: It won't be noticeable, prefer your coding style. Even if it's technically faster, there are very few cases where you'd actually need to be concerned with performance here. Optimize readability instead.

Answer (score 11):

Assuming that the types are simple, as in `int` etc., I'd be really surprised if any decent compiler didn't optimize both examples to the same code in a release build. A complex type might for instance require more horse-power in an overloaded `operator++`.

Comment: There can be difference if the types involved are not built-in types. See my answer.

Answer (score 5):

No difference at all.

And you shouldn't bother here, because `cout << test` will use 99% of the time anyway.

Almost all the simple transformations you can do to the code, the compiler can do as well. Plus some!

Trust you compiler(tm)!

Answer (score 5):

Your compiler will probably generate the same machine-level instructions in both cases. Don't bother.

Answer (score 4):

B is faster.
However, it depends on a compiler and optimization level. Smart compiler with optimizations enabled will replace A with B.

Answer (score 3):

I'd say it makes no difference, as after constant-folding/constant-propagation (typical optimization techniques of the compiler) either `limit + 5` (A) and `limit2` (B) in the for-loop will be replaced by a constant value (provided limit can be resolved to a constant value).

So **runtime** should be the same, but **compile-time** could be slightly faster for A, as B needs more constant-propagation/constant-folding iterations. But thats just nitpicking and should be unnoticeable (unless you're compiling on a [Zuse Z1](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Z1_%28computer%29))

Comment: I think we can assume that limit is not compile-time  constant in this case - but never the less the compiler should pre-calculate it

Answer (score 3):

My answer is :

It depends on the type of `i` and `limit`,since their types isn't mentioned in the question (as of now).

- If they're built-in types (such as `int`, `short`, `long`, `char` etc), then there wouldn't be much difference, not atleast noticeable difference for all practical purposes. That would also because most CPU cycles would be consumed by `cout` alone. And the smart compilers would optimize `A` (and possibly `B` as well), emitting same code for both.
- If they're some user-defined types, and the type of `i` has overloaded `operator<` and `operator++` and type of `limit` overloaded `operator+`, then it all depends on how all these functions (operator overloads involved in the code) are defined. However, its more likely that the `scenario B` would be faster since `limit2 = limit +5;` would be calculated once.

Note: in the second case, the expression `limit2 = limit +5` involves a function call which is basically this:

```
 limit2 = limit.operator+(5);
```

The *scenario B* avoids the repepition of this function call if it stays outside of the `for` loop.

Answer (score 2):

**Test it** with something "more atomic" than *cout*, and with higher number of cycles. Anyway, these sources *should* generate the very same code.

Comment: +1: "Test it" is exactly the right answer! I'd say except for really gross optimisations (e.g. not drawing graphical elements which are completely offscreen) then you should not try to outguess the compiler/optimiser.

Comment: Thx, anyway, trusting in one test is dangerous, using different compiler may produce different code and test result.

Comment: absolutely true: if you need to optimise you have to test YOUR configuration, accept no substitute!

Answer (score 0):

There will likely be no difference.

One possible reason for the 2nd loop to be faster is if the compiler is able to infer that "limit2" doesn't have it's address taken anywhere, but can't infer that about "limit". If limit has it's address taken anywhere in the program then it's possible that the operator<< function you call could alter limit via that pointer and so it has to reload and recalculate the expression each time through the loop. Whereas if you copy limit +5 into a local variable the compiler can know there is no way for a legal program to have changed it.